# Variáveis por links

Tags: php, html, ajax

É possível fazer com que não seja possível que os utilizadores não acedam a uma página do tipo "registar.php?msg=erro" por link?

Ou sejam, basicamente existe o link "registar.php" que serve para os utilizadores se registarem e o email introduzido já estava a ser utilizador, ao clicar no botão registar, o utilizador irá ser direcionado para o link "registar.php?msg=erro" que é o mesmo que o "registar.php" mas com um div a indicar o erro. Existe forma de não deixar aceder ao "registar.php?msg=erro" por link? e apenas ao clicar no botão?

Código:

registar.php

```
<div class="banner-bot" >
<div class="container">
    <h2>Registar</h2>
    <p>Preenche os dados para criar a tua conta. Quando te registares irá ser enviado um email para confirmares a conta. </p>
    <br>
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET["msg"]) && $_GET["msg"] == "erro") {
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Erro!</strong> Já existe uma conta associada ao email introduzido. Tente novamente com um email diferente.
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
<br>
</div>
<form name="registarUtilizador" action="Inserir/InserirUtilizador.php" onsubmit="return validarRegisto()" method="POST">
    <div class="register-box">
        <div class="text">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nome Completo" required=""  name="nomeCompleto" id="nomeCompleto"  maxlength="99"/>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" required="" name="email" id="email" maxlength="99"/>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Confirme o seu Email" required="" name="emailConfirmar" id="emailConfirmar" maxlength="99"/>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" name="pass" id="" maxlength="20"/>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Confirme a sua Password" required="" name="passConfirmar" id="passConfirmar" maxlength="20"/>
            <br>
            <br>
            <center><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="key"></div></center>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="text-but">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirmar"/>
        </div>  
    </div>
</form>
```

Código InserirUtilizador:

```
<?php require '../functions.php'; ?>
<body>
<?php

$nomeCompleto = $_POST["nomeCompleto"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];

$options = [
    'cost' => 12,
];
$pass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

// Create connection
$conn = db_connect(); 

$sql = "INSERT INTO utilizadores (nomeCompleto, email, pass) 
VALUES ('$nomeCompleto', '$email', '$pass')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?msg=sucesso");
} else {
    header("Location: ../registar.php?msg=erro");
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: pode postar o código dessa página registar.php

Comment: Bem-vindo Nelson Silva, você conseguirá melhores respostas se der às pessoas código que elas possam usar para reproduzir o problema. Leia esse post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Peço desculpa, já meti o código dos ficheiros

Comment: Mas existe algum link no `registar.php` que para `registar.php?msg=erro` ? Ou a ideia é "impedir" que a pessoa escreva isso diretamente no url do browser?

Comment: Sim, essa era a ideia. Tentar impedir que a pessoa escreva o "registar.php?msg=erro" no url. E apenas permitir caso a pessoa clique no botão para registar.

Comment: Caso alguma resposta solucionou seu problema marque-a como aceita, vaja como e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função `strrpos()` para ver se a string `msg=erro` está presente na URL (`$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]`) e verificar se a requisição veio direcionada de algum lugar (`$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]`).

Caso a primeira condição seja verdadeira e a segunda seja vazia, "pode ser" que a URL foi digitada diretamente no navegador:

```
<?php 
if(strrpos($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI],"msg=erro") && $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER] == ""){
    exit; // para o carregamento da página. OQ VC PRETENDE FAZER AQUI?
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um exemplo com MySQLi e sem a função `password_hash` mas vc pode adaptar para PDO e usar a função `password_hash`.

**registar.php**

Essa primeira parte em PHP só será executada caso haja redirecionamento da `InserirUtilizador.php` para cá, ou seja, se já existir o `email` na tabela `utilizadores`, momento pelo qual é inserido no URL redirecionador o parâmetro `key` que também é inserido na tabela `acesskey` na coluna `uniqueid`.

Esse PHP tem por finalidade exibir a `<div class="alert alert-danger">` caso seja acessado unica e exclusivamente através da página `InserirUtilizador.php` no caso de já existir o email cadastrado, portanto a `<div class="alert alert-danger">` não será mostrada em nenhuma outra hipótese.

```
<?php
if ($_GET['key']){
  $key= $_GET['key'];
  $conn = new mysqli("localhost","NOME_USUARIO","SENHA", "NOME_DB");

     $select = "select * from acesskey where uniqueid = '$key'";

     $result = $conn->query($select);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){

       $mostrarDiv="sim";
       $sql = ("DELETE FROM acesskey Where uniqueid='".$key."'");
       $delete = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    }
 mysqli_close($conn);
}   
?>

<div class="banner-bot" >
<div class="container">
    <h2>Registar</h2>
    <p>Preenche os dados para criar a tua conta. Quando te registares irá ser enviado um email para confirmares a conta. </p>
    <br>
    <?php
        if($mostrarDiv=="sim") {
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Erro!</strong> Já existe uma conta associada ao email introduzido. Tente novamente com um email diferente.
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
<br>
</div>
<form name="registarUtilizador" action="Inserir/InserirUtilizador.php" method="POST">
    <div class="register-box">
        <div class="text">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nome Completo" required=""  name="nomeCompleto" id="nomeCompleto"  maxlength="99"/>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" required="" name="email" id="email" maxlength="99"/>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Confirme o seu Email" required="" name="emailConfirmar" id="emailConfirmar" maxlength="99"/>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" name="pass" id="" maxlength="20"/>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Confirme a sua Password" required="" name="passConfirmar" id="passConfirmar" maxlength="20"/>
            <br>
            <br>
            <center><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="key"></div></center>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="text-but">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirmar"/>
        </div>  
    </div>
</form>
```

**Código InserirUtilizador**

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","NOME_USUARIO","SENHA", "NOME_DB");

$nomeCompleto = $_POST["nomeCompleto"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];

$result = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM utilizadores WHERE email = '$email'");

$row = $result->fetch_row();


if ($row[0] > 0) {

    $key = uniqid(md5(rand()));
    $conn->query("Insert into acesskey (uniqueid) values ('".$key."')");
    header("Location: ../registar.php?key=$key");

} else {

    $conn->query("INSERT INTO utilizadores (nomeCompleto, email, pass) VALUES ('$nomeCompleto', '$email', '$pass')");
    header("Location: ../index.php?msg=sucesso");

}

mysqli_close($conn);
```